# Java: Writing a static function that takes a string as an argument and returns the third word in the string?

Tags: java, string, static, return

> Write a static function that takes a string as an argument and returns
>   the third word in the string. Call the function with the following
>   string:
>
> *This is my string*
>
> Print the result to the console.

New to java and having a hard time figuring this problem at (new at java). Im not sure how to approach the problem. Ive figured out how to get the results with an array but is an array even a possible answer? What im having trouble with most is the returning of the 3rd word of the string.

edit:

Heres what I have currently to figure what was asked for, just not sure if its correct

```
public class problem4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str; 
        str = strArray();
        System.out.println(str[2]);
    }

    public static String[] strArray(){
        String[] array = {"This", "is", "my", "string"};
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something to solve this? If so, please post it and we gladly help you.

Comment: did you check `split()` or `substring()` and `indexof()`

Comment: Show us what you have figured out till now (In the form of code). We don't give away straight code on SO. Try to come up with a solution, and ask a specific issue with that.

Comment: I dont understand why everyone would downvote this. He is clearly new and he showed us what he tried (which is on the right track). Cut the guy some slack...

Answer (score 0):

This is on the right track, but its not exactly what the problem is asking for.

You are missing two big things here. First, you need to put this into a static function that takes a string (meaning you have to make your own, you cant use main). That would look something like this -

```
public static String getThirdWord(String s){
```

Second, your logic works assuming you get a `String` array. The problem though states you are getting a `String`. That means you have to do some work before you can use your (mostly correct) array notation. Here is what you need

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

This will take the input, and 'split' it into parts around the spaces. You are essentially getting back an array of the individual words.

Then you can start using the array notation -

```
return words[2];
```

HOWEVER: you might get an input that is less than three words! This would cause an exception to be thrown when you do `words[2]`. Your problem does not state what to do in such a case, but you will almost certinally need to check the size by doing `if(words.size>2)`

Comment: Split by single white space might cause some problem in case there are more than one spaces between words. Of course, that's special case, but need to be concerned. what about s.trim().split("\\s+")

Comment: @dragon66 Im going off the assumption that this is ideal inputs because this is a beginners problem. I dont want to make it too complicated and regexs would do just that. There are many things that are not accounted for here (ie nulls) that Im just assuming wont be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ill keep it in mind. Reason why im hesitant to use s.split is cause we havent gotten that far into the material and my upcoming test im studying for is just covering certain chapters so far.